# SKlearn SGD Partial Fit error: Number of features 378 does not match previous data 4598

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have pkl my classifier and opened in another notebook and try to do partial_fit on the classifier but received error Number of features 378 does not match previous data 4598.

```
with open("models/count_vect_Item Group.pkl", 'r') as f:
 global count_vect_item_group
 count_vect_item_group = joblib.load(f)

with open("models/model_Item Group.pkl", 'r') as f:
 global model_predicted_item_group
 model_predicted_item_group = joblib.load(f)

count_matrix_X_train = count_vect_item_group.fit_transform(X_test)
X_train_tf_idf = tf_idf(count_matrix_X_train)

model_predicted_item_group.partial_fit(X_train_tf_idf, labels_test )
```

not able to train my classifier using new dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because before you pickled your classifier, you trained it with 4598 features (number of columns in X) which in now 378 only. It should be equal to older features.

How you can do that, by calling only `count_vect_item_group.transform()`. You are now again calling the fit_transform() on the `count_vect_item_group` which then forgets about the previously learned data, and fits on the new data, hence the number of features found are lesser than before.

Change your code to:

```
count_matrix_X_train = count_vect_item_group.transform(X_test)
X_train_tf_idf = tf_idf(count_matrix_X_train)

model_predicted_item_group.partial_fit(X_train_tf_idf, labels_test)
```

Comment: what is tf_idf() in 2nd line?

Comment: @wonhee Its a method implemented by the OP in his code.

Comment: count_vect_item_group is his classifier that was stored in the file, so count_vect_item_group.transform() is going to return matrix, and what's tf_idf suppose to do here? Maybe just count_matrix_X_train.toarray() or something?

Comment: @wonhee `count_matrix_X_train` as the name suggests is a count matrix. `tf_idf` (as the name suggests) should be calculating the tf-idf values of the matrix (from the given counts). You can ping the OP to get more information.

Comment: okay.. so the original post says he pkl his classifier, but I think it's actually vectorizer? I don't think SGD classifier has things like fit_transform() or transform() at all.